# Why does a "new" method saves my relation instead of just initializing it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an Advisor model with has_one relation to Profile model, in my controller i have a profile page with following code:

```
@advisor = Advisor.includes(:profile).find(current_advisor_user.id)
@advisor.profile ||= AdvisorProfile.new
```

When i load that profile page - it create a record in database for profile, however i just want to initialise it so it is not nil in my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
@advisor.build_profile
```

It will return "a new object of the associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but has not yet been saved." See [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to).

Answer (score 5):

I think you want `@advisor.build_profile`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_one

> **association=(associate)** — Assigns the associate object, extracts the
>   primary key, sets it as the foreign key, and **saves the associate
>   object**.
>
> **build_association(attributes = {})** — Returns a new object of the
>   associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked
>   to this object through a foreign key, **but has not yet been saved**.

Comment: works perfect but i will accept Yanhao's anser because he was a first to answer. Thanks